# maven - adding dependencies for existing java struts projects

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I have an existing struts based java web project. I would like to configure maven for build and deploy. But the build fails when I add dependent a java project to it. 
Could someone provide me steps to add dependency? Also, I am using Helios eclipse.

Comment: Show information from build log

Comment: Can you show us your pom without it's hard to guess what's wrong.